# Autofac MVC5 and WebAPI2.1 not working

Tags: autofac, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

**Here is my `Bootstrap` in global.asax**

```
public class Global : HttpApplication {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            // initiate dependency injection resolver
            DependencyInjectionResolver.RegisterDependencies(typeof(Global).Assembly);
        }
    }
```

**Here is implementation**

```
public class DependencyInjectionResolver {
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static TService Resolve<TService>() {
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<TService>();
    }

    public static void RegisterDependencies(Assembly assembly) {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Repository<>))
            .As(typeof (IRepository<>))
            .InstancePerHttpRequest()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<LoggerService>()
            .As<ILoggerService>()
            .InstancePerApiRequest()
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();

        builder.Register(x =>
            new MessageDataService(Resolve<ILoggerService>(), Resolve<IRepository<ApiRequestHistory>>()))
            .As<IMessagesDataService>()
            .InstancePerHttpRequest()
            .InstancePerApiRequest();

        #region setup

        _container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver 
            = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(_container);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Here is my exception:**

```
    An error has occurred.An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MessageReportController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.System.InvalidOperationException   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()An error has occurred.Type 'WayToLead.Web.UI.api.MessageReportController' does not have a default constructorSystem.ArgumentException   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

How to fix it to work with WebApi and Mvc controllers?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with the ApiControllers, but however the MVC controllers are being resolved and constructed just fine. Are you also only having problems with the WebApi2 controllers?

Comment: Me also. I haven't resolved that issue.

Comment: I managed to work it out. Deep inside an inner exception or two I noticed that what was really happening was that I had an unregistered dependency that was required by a dependency of the api controller. After I registered it, it started working awesomely.

Comment: @enriquein add it to answers I will gladly set it out as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have registered all of your ApiControllers' dependencies and sub-dependencies. Somewhere deep inside the stack trace you might find exacly which dependency AutoFac wasn't able to resolve.

I'm guessing that since AutoFac couldn't satisfy all dependencies then the default dependency resolver takes over.

Comment: I will check it out and get back at ya. Thanks.